# Changing CSS property with Javascript using arguments

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, typescript

Basically, I want the ability for a user to select the color of the buttons on the page. I'm using Angular 6 + JS.

Right now, I'm just working on setting the primary color (and therefore, only effecting buttons with the bootstrap class of `.btn-primary`

I have a color wheel which on change is sending hex values to a function. The function converts the hex value to rgb, it then, using `querySelectorAll`, gathers all the .`btn-primary` buttons on the page. It then attempts to loop over each button and set the background color and border color to the color that was passed to the function via the argument.

HTML (requires ngx-color-picker & bootstrap import package):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
<div class="form-group mt-2">
  <label class="d-block" for="setPrimaryColor">Set primary color</label>
  <input 
    (colorPickerChange)="setPrimaryColor($event)" 
    id="setPrimaryColor" 
    [(colorPicker)]="color" 
    [style.background]="color"
    [cpOutputFormat]='auto'/>
</div>
```

TS/JS/NG6

```
heroGradient1 = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
heroGradient2 = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
primaryColor: string = '';

setPrimaryColor(color) {
        this.heroGradient1 = this.hexToRgb(color) + ', 0.1)';
        this.heroGradient2 = this.hexToRgb(color) + ', 0.8)';
        this.primaryColor = this.hexToRgb(color);
    
        const primaryBtns = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.btn-primary');
        console.log(primaryBtns)
        primaryBtns.forEach(element => {
          element.style.setProperty('background-color', this.primaryColor);
          element.style.setProperty('border-color', this.primaryColor);
        });
}

hexToRgb(hex){
    var c;
    if(/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)){
        c= hex.substring(1).split('');
        if(c.length== 3){
            c= [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
        }
        c= '0x'+c.join('');
        return 'rgba('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',');
    }
    throw new Error('Bad Hex');
}
```

The console log is confirming the `querySelectorAll` is picking up all btn primaries on the page, but the for loop isn't altering the background or border colors. Any help?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: updated to include html and package library for the color wheel required

Comment: There aren't any buttons in your example. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay, added a button with a class of .btn-primary

Comment: removing <HTMLElement> from `document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>` allowed it to work for me.

Comment: how? without casting element.style throws an error for me

Comment: @J.G.Sable I didn't see the Angular JS part, with basic javascript (https://jsfiddle.net/7g8Lc9tn/) it works just fine by removing that.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/y4r1ft5x/

Comment: because you're not casting. If I don't cast, I get a "property style does not exist on type Element' error from TS

Comment: @J.G.Sable Sorry, I can't really help then since there's no example of the problem like a JSFiddle.

Comment: I got it. Introduces a new issue, but the style rule wasn't overriding the fact that the original btn-primary class had an !important flag on it.

Answer (score 0):

***1.***    Your `hexToRgb` function return broken value. you have to close brackets.

Also, `rgba` expect 4 parameters (including alpha). better use `rgb` (although rgba will also work..)

Change

```
    return 'rgba('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',');
```

to

```
    return 'rgb('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',')+')';
```

***2.***    The bootstrap `.btn-primary` class have an `!important` priority styles. if you want to override it, you should have this priorities as well.

For this, add `important` as the third argument of the `setProperty` function.

change

```
  element.style.setProperty('background-color', this.primaryColor);
  element.style.setProperty('border-color', this.primaryColor);
```

to

```
  element.style.setProperty('background-color', this.primaryColor, 'important');
  element.style.setProperty('border-color', this.primaryColor, 'important');
```

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't the issue though.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Also, please take a look at the edit, new issue founded&resolved